# How to turn template literal into html in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this code here:

```
import React from 'react';

var article = {
  title: 'Hello World',
 }

const App = () => {
  var {title} = article
  var html = `<header>
    <h1>${title}</h1>
  </header>`
  return <div>{html}</div>;
}
```

and I am getting this in the page as `<header> <h1>Hello World</h1> </header>` instead of usual html.

How do I turn the string literal into HTML in react? Thanks a lot and in advance.

Comment: Why are you using a template literal when you can use JSX directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, template literals are string literals.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

You can just remove the template literal :)

```
var article = {
  title: 'Hello World',
 }

const App = () => {
  var {title} = article
  var html = <header>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
  </header>
  return <div>{html}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with React's **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** but as you can tell from the name, it is dangerous because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a [cross-site scripting (XSS) attack](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

You can still use it if you understand the risk:

```
import React from 'react';

var article = {
  title: "Hello World"
};

const App = () => {
  var { title } = article;
  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `<header><h1>${title}</h1></header>`
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

If you are just trying to embed expressions in JSX, simply wrap them in curly braces:

```
import React from "react";

var article = {
  title: "Hello World"
};

const App = () => {
  var { title } = article;
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the variable `html` is just a string, and when you try to render it inside the jsx like `<div>{html}</div>` it is explicitly being rendered as a string rather than HTML.

It is nothing different than trying to render `<div>{"<header>Hello There</header>"}</div>`. While saving to the result that you want to a variable works, I wouldn't recommend it. For your use-case it is much simpler to just use JSX directly instead. For example,

```js
var article = {
  title: "Hello World"
};

const App = () => {
  var { title } = article;
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you have a lot of elements that you were trying to render, abstracting the logic to a new component is always a better idea. For example,

```js
// new Header component
const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <header>
       <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      {/* other-components or elements you want to render */}
    </header>
  );
}


var article = {
  title: "Hello World"
};

const App = () => {
  var { title } = article;
  return (
    <div>
      <Header title={title}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```